# What causes the Object DOMDocument should be created error?

Tags: magento2

I'm currently modifying a converted Magento 1.9 module to be used for Magento-2 but i keep getting this error:

> Object DOMDocument should be created

It happens every time I try to access the login page.

I put the module in a GitHub project found [here](https://github.com/CallumBrankin/Magento2-Inchoo-Social-Plugin).

If anyone can tell me what normally causes this error that'd be great.

system.log stack:

```
[2016-11-10 12:01:21] main.CRITICAL: Class Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Google\Client does not exist [] []
[2016-11-10 12:01:21] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login [] []
[2016-11-10 12:01:21] main.CRITICAL: Class Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Google\Client does not exist [] []
[2016-11-10 12:01:21] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Google\Button [] []
[2016-11-10 12:01:21] main.CRITICAL: Class Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Facebook\Client does not exist [] []
[2016-11-10 12:01:21] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Facebook\Button [] []
[2016-11-10 12:01:21] main.CRITICAL: Class Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Twitter\Client does not exist [] []
[2016-11-10 12:01:21] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Twitter\Button [] []
[2016-11-10 12:01:21] main.CRITICAL: Class Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Pixelpin\Client does not exist [] []
[2016-11-10 12:01:21] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Pixelpin\Button [] []
```

Comment: You need to deploy the content using `setup:static-content:deploy` command It will generate files in `var/genaration` folder. It will remove this error i think and remove contents in var/generation, var/cache before deploying contents.

Comment: Which file and which line are you getting the error ?

Comment: @NitinPawar I do that everytime i update the module

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism The error doesn't say much, i'll edit the question with the error log

Comment: @NitinPawar In fact i haven't been removing the contents in var/generation and var cache, i'll try that now

Comment: @NitinPawar I just tried it, same error

Comment: Make sure `var\genaration` file is writable by web server. Also try to deploy content after deleting the module folder in `pub\static\frontend\vendor_name\theme_name\lang_pref`. Try it, may it help.

Comment: @NitinPawar  I've updated the question with my system.log